# GDAL C# ReadAsArray

Tags: c#, geospatial, gdal

I was using GDAL API to read raster files... I found in some places that python version has ReadAsArray, I assume this takes the data of the raster file as two dimensional array, is there any similar option for C#, or at least can you show me how to do it? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

There is no equivalent of [ReadAsArray](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython) function available in C# bindings to GDAL. The ReadAsArray is available because GDAL Python bindings are supposed to be usable with array protocol defined by [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) so this function exists for this specific purpose.

However, you can use ReadRaster method of Band class to read pixels into 1-dimension array and then iterate over such 1-dimension array as it was 2-dimension array.

Let's assume you read pixels of a band with `width x height` dimensions:

```
byte[] bits = new byte[width * height];
band.ReadRaster(0, 0, width, height, bits, width, height, 0, 0);
```

Now, you can calculate index of a pixel according to this formula: `column + row * width`

```
for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        // equivalent to bits[col][row] if bits is 2-dimension array

        byte pixel = bits[col + row * width];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ReadAsArray(0,0, xsize, ysize)` function in Python version is equivalent to the `ReadRaster(0,0, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, dstArray, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, 0)` in C# version.